# Single stage CMOS amplifier PSpice design

Tags: amplifier, cmos, pspice

I'm at the very beginning of my electronics adventure and facing the given problem: I'm trying to design a single-ended CMOS amplifier with small signal gain = 15dB at 10kHz. The load capacitance has to be Cl=1pF and the DC input voltage (Common mode voltage) is Vcm=0.6V

The next thing is to design a differential amplifier with small signal gain = 30dB at 10kHz, Cl=1pF and DC input voltage (Common mode voltage) Vcm=1.2V

I believe it is quite simple, but as I mentioned, I'm at the very beginning of getting electronics to know and I'm finding it tricky. The Internet didn't really help me out, so I thought that someone here could give me some guidance. I'm not even sure what MOSFET to use, I was thinking about the Si7336ADP (https://www.vishay.com/docs/73152/si7336adp.pdf) that is available in PSpice.

Comment: Please use the circuit tool and draw a schematic (edit)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.